# Controlling plots with sliders without using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Why are the sliders in the following code not affecting the plot? (Without using `Manipulate`)

```
Module[{t, o, z}, f[t]];
{Slider[ Dynamic[o], {1, 5, 0.1}], Dynamic[o]}
{Slider[ Dynamic[z], {0.1, 1.4, 0.1}], Dynamic[z]}
{Slider[ Dynamic[Ts], {5, 20, 1}], Dynamic[Ts]}
tf[o_, z_] := TransferFunctionModel[ω^2/(s^2 + 2 z o s + o^2), s];
f[t] = OutputResponse[tf[o, z], UnitStep[t], t];
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {{0, T}, {0, 2}}]
```

Comment: And why do you think a Plot should be affected by a slider?

Comment: Because f[t] depends on o, z and t

Comment: why write `Module[{t, o, z}, f[t]];` on its own? what it means like this? code give error running. fix bug in code, not good to post code with coding error. bad for other people to waste time on it.

Comment: Seems you cross posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412166/manipulate-does-not-accept-constant-i-e-just-number-as-upper-limit-for-variab/11412928#11412928

Answer (score 6):

Your code modified and with syntax errors fixed

```
DynamicModule[{o, z, capTs, ω, s},
tf[o_, z_, ω_, s] := TransferFunctionModel[ω^2/(s^2 + 2 z o s + o^2), s];
f[t_, o_, z_, ω_] := OutputResponse[tf[o, z, ω, s], UnitStep[t], t];
Grid[{{"o", Slider[Dynamic[o], {1, 5, 0.1}], Dynamic[o]},
 {"z", Slider[Dynamic[z], {0.1, 1.4, 0.1}], Dynamic[z]},
 {"ω", Slider[Dynamic[ω], {0.1, 1.4, 0.1}], Dynamic[ω]},
 {"Ts", Slider[Dynamic[capTs], {5, 20, 1}], Dynamic[capTs]}, 
 {Dynamic@ Plot[Evaluate@f[t, o, z, ω], {t, 0, capTs}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, capTs}, {0, Automatic}}], SpanFromLeft}}]]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems is that you use `Set` (`=`) to define `f[t]`. This means that `f[t]` will be equal to the evaluated form of the right-hand side of its definition where `o` and `z` are replaced by their values as they were at the time that `f` was defined.

What you want is `SetDelayed` (`:=`) which leaves the right-hand side in its unevaluated form. In that case the right-hand side will be re-evaluated with the current values for `o` and `z` every time `f` is called.

The second issue is that to get a plot that is updated dynamically, you would need to do something `Dynamic[Plot[f[t], ...]]`. I don't have access to Mathematica at the moment but I suspect that since `o` and `z` don't appear explicitly in `Plot[f[t],...]` you would also need to set `TrackedSymbols -> {o, z}` in `Dynamic[Plot[...]]`.